# Preview and upload react-native-camera recorded video

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-fs

I'm trying to implement a camera in a React-native app. The goal of the application is to record a video and upload it and then delete it from the phone. I managed to record the video using react-native-camera.

React-native-camera returns a path for the recorded video. I tried putting this path in react-native-video. But this makes the application crash. Do i have to use something like react-native-fs to load the video for react-native-video or how do i do this?

This makes the application crash, even though this.props.file.path have the path of the recorded video which looks like this on Android:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Vid_xxxxxxx_xxxxx.mp4

```
<Video source={{uri : this.props.file.path}}
                   style={styles.fullScreen}
                   rate={1.0}
                   volume={1.0}
                   muted={false}
                   resizeMode={"cover"}
                   onEnd={() => { console.log('Done!') }}
                   repeat={true} />
                   <StatusBar navigator={this.props.navigator} next={this.go.bind(this)}/>
```

If i save the video to the cameraRoll it's there as expected.

Comment: Can you post the crash log pls..

Comment: @Jickson It doesn't output anything in the console, but i quickly get this error picture:
https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/14885995_10211005678314795_944235186_n.png?oh=c524e5db88e4c2c7c8b7bde57af76aad&oe=5819B3AC

Comment: oh... Pic doesn't help in debugging the error.

Comment: Did you try 'react-native log-android' command to  see the error log?

Comment: @Jickson react-native log-android doesn't output anything when the app crashes. What am i doing wrong? tried with both JS Debugging on and off

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you have posted. May be the issue is somewhere else. It would be helpful if you can create a sample project in Github to reproduce the issue and share the link here.

Comment: I figured out i works if the video is SUPER short - like 5 seconds but if it's over 10 seconds it makes the app crash. How do i solve this?

Comment: i was crashing because i was using react-native-video with high resolution, which resulted in 4k videos. Switching the captureformat to medium made it possible for me to make longer videos.

Comment: Nice to see you identified the issue. Please create an issue https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/new so that its addressed in library.

Comment: Facing the same issue can anyone help me out with this ---
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892807/react-native-camera-video-capturing-shows-error-on-preview-after-it-gets-capture